# Metric spaces, compactness, how to solve this with the open covering property?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have an excercise I am supposed to solve with the open covering property. I am not able to do that, but I can solve it with another method. I have two questions.

**1. Is my method of solving it correct?**

**2. Can you please tell me how to solve it using that the open covering property is equivalent with compactness?**

excercise:

> Let $K_{n}$ be a decreasing sequence (i.e., $K_{n+1} \subseteq K_{n}$
>   for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$) of nonempty, compact sets. Show that
>    $\bigcap_{n \in N}K_{n} \ne \emptyset. $

solution without using open-covering property:

> For each $K_{n}$ choose an element in $K_{n}$. Since the higher sets
>   are contained in each other, all of these elements will be a sequence
>   $\{x_{n}\}$ in $K_{1}$. Since $K_{1}$ is compact there will be a
>   subsequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ converging to a point $a$ in $K_{1}$.
>
> Assume for contradiction that $a \not\in \cap_{n \in N}K_{n}$. Then for a
>   large anough N, $a$ will not be an element in
>   $K_{N},K_{N+1},K_{N+1}....$. Since $K_{N}$ is compact and $d(x_{n},a)$
>   is continuous, by the extreme value theorem $d(x_{n},a)$ will be
>   bigger than  $min\{d(x,a): x \in K_{N}\}$ for all $n \ge N=M>0$. And
>   this distance can not be zero since a is not in this set. Hence the subsequence can not converge
>   to a as assumed.

Is my sollution correct, and how can it be done with the open covering property instead?

Answer (score 1):

My knowledge on sequences is minimal but I can tell you how to solve it using the open covering method.

Consider the sequence of sets $F_n = (K_n)^c$. If the intersection is empty then there is no common point in the sequence $\{K_n\}$ and hence the union $\bigcup_{n \in \Bbb N} F_n$ contains $K_1$. Now since each $K_n$ is compact they are alsoo closed. Hence $F_n$ is open and $\bigcup F_n$ is an open covering of $K_1$ which is compact.

Therefore, there is a finite subsequence, $F_{i_1}, F_{i_2}, .. F_{i_m}$ of $F_n$ which is also a covering of $K_1$. Now if $M = \text{Max} \ \{ i_n \}$ then since each $F_n$ increases in size, $F_{i_1} \subseteq F_{i_2} \subseteq, .. F_{i_m} \subseteq F_M$. Therefore $F_M$ contains $K_1$.

But $K_M \subseteq K_1 \implies K_M \cap K_1 = K_M$. Since $K_1 \cap F_M = K_1$ we have $K_M \cap (K_1 \cap F_M) = K_M \implies (K_M \cap F_M) \cap K_1 = K_M \implies \emptyset = K_M$ which is a contradiction since every member of $K_n$ is non-empty.

Therefore the sequence has a common point and hence the intersection is non-empty.

Comment: @user119615: Anytime..

Answer (score 0):

It looks pretty good to me.

I think that you lose the plot a little when you start talking about the continuity of the distance function, but not in any serious way.  Your contradiction argument will work in a simpler way: Once you have an $N$ such that $a\notin K_N$, the contradiction is immediate since all but finitely many terms of the convergent subsequence are contained in the closed set $K_{N}$. QED

The open covering property approach is pretty simple.  Let $U_n$ be the complement of $K_n$.  Then if the intersection is empty, these sets form an open cover for each compact set $K_n$.  A contradiction follows from there - I'll let you finish it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove something more general, if you want.

> *Claim* Let $\mathscr F=\{K_\alpha:\alpha\in A\}$ be a family of centered compact sets in a Hausdorff space, that is, any finite intersection of elements of $\mathscr F$ is nonempty. Then $\bigcap \mathscr F$ is nonempty.

*Proof* Suppose not. Then there exists some $K_0\in \mathscr F$ such that  for each $x\in K_0$ there is $K_{\alpha_x}$ with $x\notin K_{\alpha_x}$. Since the space is Hausdorff, our compact sets are also closed, so the sets $V_{\alpha_x}=K_{\alpha_x}^c$ are an open cover of $K_0$. This means there exists a finite subcover $V_1,\ldots,V_n$ such that $K_0\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n V_i$ that is $$K_0 \cap (K_1\cap\cdots\cap K_n)=\varnothing$$

which contradicts $\mathscr F$ is centered. $\blacktriangleleft$